# react-native run-android freezes on deleting Gradle directory

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to run a React Native app:

> `react-native run-android`

however when I do so I get these messages:

> info Starting JS server...
>
> info Installing the app...
>
> Deleting directory C:\Users\edkol\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.4.1-all\3221gyojl5jsh0helicew7rwx\gradle-5.4.1

and the app never runs, even if I have an emulator open prior to running the command.

How do I get the app to run?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

All I do with this problem is **WAIT** as first it deletes that folder then it decompressed it. This Process takes some time. You can see the Progress by visiting that directory then check Properties (It Continues ADDING volume in it) **[IT takes up-to 5 minutes]**